# PrimeFaces GMap ignores model tag, not displaying markers

Tags: java, google-maps, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem using the GMap in PrimeFaces 5.2
I am trying to show a map window with a single marker, but the marker does not show up, I keep getting the blank map without the marker. After investigating I found that apparently the model tag in the XHTML file is being ignored. Even if I fill in complete nonsense (like model="#{asdfasdf}) it doesn't even throw an error.

Snippets of my code:

XHTML

```
        <p:outputPanel id="mapPanel" style="text-align:center;width:400px">
            <p:gmap id="map" rendered="#{testRecordsView.showMap}"
                model="#{GMapView.simpleModel}" zoom="10" type="ROADMAP"
                center="#{testRecordsView.selectedTest.lat}, #{testRecordsView.selectedTest.lng}"
                style="width:400px;height:400px" />
        </p:outputPanel>
```

GMapView.java

```
@ManagedBean
public class GMapView implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2238997881933594120L;

private MapModel simpleModel;

@ManagedProperty("#{testRecordsView}")
private TestRecordsView dtView;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    System.out.println("MAPMAPMAP");
    simpleModel = new DefaultMapModel();

    LatLng coord1 = new LatLng(dtView.getSelectedTest().getLat(), dtView.getSelectedTest().getLng());

    // Basic marker
    simpleModel.addOverlay(new Marker(coord1, "test"));
}

public MapModel getSimpleModel() {
    System.out.println("Map: " + simpleModel + " !");
    return simpleModel;
}

public void setDtView(TestRecordsView dtView) {
    this.dtView = dtView;
}
```

}

The prints in the GMapView never occur and if I put breakpoints somewhere in the class, they are not activated either. Apparently the whole class is never called. Has anybody had this problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line:

```
model="#{GMapView.simpleModel}" zoom="10" type="ROADMAP"
```

put the g in lowercase at start ;-)

```
model="#{gMapView.simpleModel}" zoom="10" type="ROADMAP"
```

There you go.

Comment: That fixes it. Also found an alternative solution by explicitly setting the name for the bean

     @ManagedBean (name = "GMapView")